# Sorting a table C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a table of numbers that look like this:

```
2 8 4 0
3 1 0 9
1 2 3 4
5 4 14 2
```

I put all the numbers in an array `{ 2,8,4,0,3,1... }`. Is there a way to sort it by the first column only using a 1D array so that it ends up like this:

```
1 2 3 4
2 8 4 0
3 1 0 9
5 4 14 2
```

I know there's a way of doing it with a 2D array, but, assuming I know the number of columns, is it possible with only a 1D array?

Comment: I assume you know the number of columns in the table? Otherwise the problem is ill  formed.

Comment: "is it possible" sure.  Should you be revisiting your data structures?  Definately

Comment: For any "X dimensional" array you can emulate it in "1d" space using simple arithmetic. Doing it for "2d" matrices are very common so it shouldn't be hard to find out the arithmetic expression needed. When you have that you can easily find all elements of a specific column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For arrays of non-user defined types it is easy to do the task using the standard C function `qsort`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int cmp( const void *a, const void *b )
{
    const int *left  = static_cast<const int *>( a );
    const int *right = static_cast<const int *>( b );

    return ( *right < *left ) - ( *left < *right );
}

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 4;
    int a[N * N] =
    {
        2, 8, 4, 0, 3, 1, 0, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 14, 2 
    };


    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            std::cout << a[N * i + j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }        

    std::cout << '\n';

    std::qsort( a, N, sizeof( int[N] ), cmp );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            std::cout << a[N * i + j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }        

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
2 8 4 0 
3 1 0 9 
1 2 3 4 
5 4 14 2 

1 2 3 4 
2 8 4 0 
3 1 0 9 
5 4 14 2
```

So all you need is to write the function

```
int cmp( const void *a, const void *b )
{
    const int *left = static_cast<const int *>( a );
    const int *right = static_cast<const int *>( b );

    return ( *right < *left ) - ( *left < *right );
}
```

and add just one line in your program

```
std::qsort( a, N, sizeof( int[N] ), cmp );
```

Comment: What if I add more rows? For example `int a[N * N] =
    {
        2, 8, 4, 0, 3, 1, 0, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 14, 2,2,4,4,4,3,0,0,0
    };`

Comment: @Vincent The code does not depend on the value of N.

Comment: @Vincent If the number of rows does not equal to the number of columns then you need to introduce two constants M and N for rows and columns correspondingly. In this case the size of the one-dimensional array will look like int a[M * N] and the call of qsort will look like std::qsort( a, M, sizeof( int[N] ), cmp );

Comment: @Vincent Also the outer loop that outputs the array will look evidently like for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ ) the inner loop will be unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create an array of indexes into your data, and then sort those indexes;  this will save a decent number of the copies.

Your sort would then examine the value of the number at the given index.

ie for your example - indexes would be 1,2,3,4
and then sorted would read 3,1,2,4

edit:  this was 1 based; the code 0 based.  Makes no difference.

Essentially converting your 1d array into 2.  Since the bulk of your data is still contiguous (especially for large numbers of columns) reading should still be fast.

Example code:

```
std::vector<int> getSortedIndexes(std::vector<int> data, int size) {
    int count = data.size() / size;
    std::vector<int> indexes(count);

    // fill in indexes from 0 to "count" since that's the size of our vector
    std::iota(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), 0);

    // don't write your own sorting implementation .... really; don't.
    std::sort(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), [data, size](int indexA, int indexB) {
               return data[indexA*size] < data[indexB*size];
             });
    return indexes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bubblesort:

```
void sort_by_name(int* ValueArray, int NrOfValues, int RowWidth)
{
    int CycleCount = NrOfValues / RowWidth;
    int temp;
    (int j = 0; j < CycleCount ; j++) 
    {
       for (int i = 1; i < (CycleCount - j); i++) 
       {
           if(ValueArray[((i-1)*RowWidth)] > ValueArray[(i*RowWidth)]) 
           {
              for(int k = 0; k<RowWidth; k++)
              {
                  temp = ValueArray[(i*RowWidth)+k]
                  ValueArray[(i*RowWidth)+k] = ValueArray[((i-1)*RowWidth)+k];
                  ValueArray[((i-1)*RowWidth)+k] = temp;
              }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

**keep in mind that simply making your array 2D will be a MUCH BETTER solution**

edit: variable naming

Comment: There is no need to use a bad sorting algorithm only because the problem appears a bit non-standard.

Comment: You can use any sorting algorithm, I simply wanted to point out how you can compare just the "first value of a column" and move the full column